# How does Stack Overflow implement resize for WMD?

Tags: support, editor

It resizes the textarea when moving the div.grippie. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use [TextAreaResizer](https://web.archive.org/web/20090220162506/http://plugins.jquery.com/project/TextAreaResizer).

You can find the Stack Exchange version on their Development CDN as part of

[wmd.en.js](http://dev.sstatic.net/Js/wmd.en.js)

In that source from `jquery.textarearesizer.js` onward  you'll find:

```
jQuery TextAreaResizer plugin
Created on 17th January 2008 by Ryan O'Dell 
Version 1.0.4
```

The current internal SE version is

```
1.0.5 Fixed a bug in dynamic html and IE7 - Geoff Dalgas
```