# Make the question box with resizable/draggable (example: textarea)

Tags: feature-request, questions, editor

I cannot see the whole question of mine in the question box, but the preview shows me...

All I want it to work on the question box. Can that be resizable/draggable to some more lines?

Comment: At the bottom of the textarea there is a grip bar which allows you to resize the text-area.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24160/158100

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

It's a tiny, but fiddly, but the grey bar at the bottom of the text box with the dots can be dragged down, as shown.

Also it seems to work on answers. It seems to work both on sites with the new responsive design, and with it turned off.